# Twitter search api result not return same from advance web

Tags: api, search, twitter

search from advanced search on twitter web
`https://twitter.com/search?l=&q=kidspot%20%23kidspot%20%40kidspotsocial&src=typd&lang=en`

and followed the instruction of twitter search api, I called this
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Kidspot%20%23Kidspot%20%40KidspotSocial`
and only return 1 result.

Did I miss anything for the twitter search api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. The index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.

Looking at [recent tweets](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=kidspot%20%23kidspot%20%40kidspotsocial&src=typd&lang=en), there is exactly 1.